# Django: How to access other model's primary key in urlpatterns?

Tags: python, django

I am getting `NoReverseMatch` when routing to a specific path.

It is not able to find the primary key `<int:pk>` for only one *urlpattern* while getting results for all other similar paths.

I am assuming this error is because the model here is different, ex,

Not getting error for:

```
class PostUpdateView():
   model = A
```

and the error I am getting is for:

```
class AddCommentView():
   model = B
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name = 'post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment', AddCommentView.as_view(), name = 'post-comment')]
```

Both classes are in same *views.py* file because I need model A's primary key in my routing url so that I can reverse to the original page.

Error:

```
Reverse for 'post-comment' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment$']
```

What is the correct way to include both models' keys in same route?

Note: A's primary key is present in B as foreign key.

Comment: You are not passing specific ID for in URL routing, because you mentioned in urls.py `post/<int:pk>/comment` that means url reverse need id also for generate url dynamically

Comment: @NeerajKumar I tried to pass different keys but getting same error.

Comment: show me some code what you did for generate URL?

Answer (score 0):

You `get_absolute_url` method should look like this the `kwargs` argument.

```
from django.urls import reverse

class AddCommentView():
   model = B

   def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('post-comment', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```